# Indexing/Ranking/Caching Issue

Tags: seo, google-search, search-engine-indexing, google-index, server

I am hoping someone can help me out. I co-run a support site for people with mental health problems and suicidal feelings. We scoop up the folks that are searching for suicide methods pulling them away from toxic sites that encourage them to die and to a peer support site encouraging them to seek help and support.

For the last couple of years the articles on our wordpress bridge have ranked really well and we have helped a lot of people.

Right now, I have all kinds of issues suddenly:

- Some articles indexed in Google.com but not Google.co.uk e.g:
- Some aticles not caching (e.g: https://www.suicideforum.com/2016/03/27/painless-suicide-methods-pain-free-death/)
- Some articles that cannot be fetched by Google at all (e.g: https://www.suicideforum.com/2016/02/15/suicide-methods-10-ways-to-die/
- Some articles that did rank top 5 that are indexed and cached but
  just gone from Google SERPs (e.g: https://www.suicideforum.com/2017/01/03/i-want-to-kill-myself/)

I am really anxious about it because these articles are how we drew people away from sites full of methods and hate and we used to have hundreds of people a day seeking support and getting help and now due to (presumably) some tech issue I don't know how to fix, people are slipping through.

I checked search console - the one that can't be fetched I can't see any issue. Robots txt is fine. The rest, even the ones not getting cached suddenly, are inspected and says everything is okay. Site maps are submitted and successful.

Please can ANYONE help?

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: These are the few steps for initial diagnosis: 1) check robots.txt and see if you aren’t blocking any content 2) check sitemap.xml and see if these pages are included 3) check your Google search console -> crawl error, indexing report etc. 4) use search console and try to fetch these articles as Google 5) check if your sitemap is properly indexed 6) check your CMS and ensure if you are not blocking in any other ways .. hope these steps help.

Comment: Google also rolled out an update on 1st August 2018 known as Medic Update. This might be one of the prime cause. Have it read here on Search Engine Land: https://searchengineland.com/googles-august-first-core-algorithm-update-who-did-it-impact-and-how-much-303538

Comment: The Google cache may be having some issues in the last few weeks.   We've had at least two other questions from folks that were seeing 404 errors from the Google cache, or no cache links in the search results for their newer pages.

Comment: I noticed that many websites on mental and health topics suffer rank drops. I've seen some of this discussion in Reddit. Google has rolled out a broad update I think earlier this month (August). Your website might be one of those that got hit.